# manipulating the output of itertools.permutations in python

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I want to take a list, for instance `List = [1,2,2]`, and generate its permutations. I can do this with:

```
NewList = [list(itertools.permutations(List))]
```

and the output is:

```
[[(1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1)]]
```

The Problem: `itertools.permutations` returns a list of length 1 whose only entry is the list of all permutations of List. That is:

```
NewList[0] == [(1,2,2),(1,2,2),(2,1,2),(2,2,1),(2,1,2),(2,2,1)]
```

and

`NewList[1]` does not exist.

I want the output to be a list where each entry is one of the permutations. That is

```
NewList[0] == (1,2,2)
NewList[1] == (1,2,2)
NewList[2] == (2,1,2)
...
NewList[5] == (2,2,1)
```

The Question: Is there a command that will produce the permutations of List in this way? Failing that, is there a way to access the 'individual elements' of `[list(itertools.permutations(List))]` so I can do things with them?

Comment: Just remove the `[]` and the output you've posted is also incorrect, it should be : `[[(1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1)]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> list(permutations([1,2,2]))
[(1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1)]
```

You don't need to put it in a list again. i.e Don't do `[list(permutations(...))]` (By doing `[]` you are making a nested list and hence are unable to access the elements using `testList[index]`, though you could do `testList[0][index]` but it would be better to just keep it as a list of tuples.)

```
>>> newList = list(permutations([1, 2, 2]))
>>> newList[0]
(1, 2, 2)
>>> newList[3]
(2, 2, 1)
```

Now you can access the elements by using their indices.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do this:

```
NewList = [list(itertools.permutations(List))][0]
```

or even just this:

```
NewList = list(itertools.permutations(List))
```

By doing `[ list(itertools.permutations(List)) ]`, you put the list of permutations (the one that you want) inside of another list.  So the fix would be to remove the outer `[]`'s